# Is the following function onto?

Tags: functions

Is the function $y = x^3$ an onto function for $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ mapping?

My attempt was that it is not, because for $y = 7$ (which belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$), $x$ (cube root of $7$) does not belong to $\mathbb{Z}$. Is that right?

Thank you!

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right.  In fact it misses all the elements of $\Bbb Z$ which aren't perfect cubes.